# Ubuntu Bash SQL Problems

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu

I am working on a script most of it works fine until it gets to line 27 of it. Which is where I have the script login to MySQL as root, create a new database and then exit MySQL.

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE databasename;exit;" | mysql -h localhost -u root -p --password=passwordhere
```

Am I calling the command correctly because it fails on this line every time and how would I fix it?

OS is Ubuntu 10.10 32 bit.

Error: ./install: line 27:  mysql: command not found

Comment: "it fails on this line every time"  How exactly does it fail?  Does it give an error message?  What is the error message?

Comment: Maybe the databasename is a reserved word? Maybe the database exists already? Please post your exact error message.

Comment: It was something like MySQL command not found line 27

Comment: Exact error: ./install: line 27:  mysql: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing this:

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u root --password=password -e "CREATE DATABASE databasename;"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to type "exit", when you pass the SQL commands through stdin - just use

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE databasename" | mysql -h localhost -u root -p --password=passwordhere
```

HTH,

good luck,

a.

Comment: So once it moves on to the next command it will drop out of SQL mode?

Comment: Still get error: Exact error: ./install: line 27:  mysql: command not found

Comment: The 'mysql: command not found' means your bash doesn't found mysql - but if it's true, I don't understand why did you get the original error message? (Is this question was modified?)